# Can primordial black holes comprise not only dark matter but also account for dark energy?

Tags: dark-matter, dark-energy

Hawking proposed primordial black holes might comprise dark matter. They certainly contribute then to dark energy via their mass and other energies; e.g. gravitational and kinetic. Does this account for dark energy?

Comment: Related, possible duplicates: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/10132/is-there-a-connection-between-black-holes-and-dark-matter-energy https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/19336/could-undiscovered-smaller-black-holes-within-galaxies-be-an-explanation-for-dar